# Counting the number of storms and listing their names?

Tags: r, count, pipe

The question is: Count the number of storms per year since 1975 and write their names
What I have so far is the code below:

```
storms %>% 
 count(name, year >= 1975, sort = TRUE)
```

I got this output:

```
name      `year >= 1975`     n
   <chr>     <lgl>          <int>
 1 Emily     TRUE             217
 2 Bonnie    TRUE             209
 3 Alberto   TRUE             184
 4 Claudette TRUE             180
 5 Felix     TRUE             178
 6 Danielle  TRUE             165
 7 Josephine TRUE             165
 8 Edouard   TRUE             159
 9 Gordon    TRUE             158
10 Gabrielle TRUE             157
```

I think this is the correct output, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Please provide sample data to get a clear answer. Your code is not giving you 'the number of storms per year since 1975 '
HINT: You might need group_by & summarize 4/tally from dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `year >= 1975` part should be in `filter` and not in `count`. However, the data starts from 1975 so your output is correct as well. You get the same output even if you remove `filter` part from the below code.

```
library(dplyr)
storms %>%  filter(year >= 1975) %>% count(name, sort = TRUE)

# A tibble: 214 × 2
#   name          n
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 Emily       217
# 2 Bonnie      209
# 3 Alberto     184
# 4 Claudette   180
# 5 Felix       178
# 6 Danielle    165
# 7 Josephine   165
# 8 Edouard     159
# 9 Gordon      158
#10 Gabrielle   157
# … with 204 more rows
```

Comment: When I do use the group_by and summarize function, it gives me a different set of names, what is the difference in using the group_by and summarize?

Comment: Yes, you can get the same output with `group_by` and `summarize` by `storms %>% group_by(name) %>%  summarise(n = n())` but the order is different. If you remove `sort = TRUE` from `count` the order is same for both.